# XPath query not working in C#

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007">
  <cd country="USA">
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="UK">
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <price>10.0</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="USA">
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

-------------------  And Following code---

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(@"C:\Temp\tmp\data1.xml");
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
var nl = document.SelectNodes("catalog/cd[@country='UK']", nsmgr);
```

---

document.SelectNodes  won't return anything. When I remove the name space on the element Catalog ( second line of the xml) it works fine. So its something with the namespace. How do I make it work? what am I doing wrong?

thanks
gulumal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to add the namespace from the document into your `NamespaceManager`

```
 var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
 // add extra namespace with prefix "s"
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007");
```

Then you query do like so (notice the use of "s" as a namespace prefix):

```
 var nl = document.SelectNodes("s:catalog/s:cd[@country='UK']", nsmgr);
```

Comment: You are right on the money! What does "s" stand for? Is it a code for default name space?

Comment: "s" can be anything you assign in the `AddNamespace("s", "urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007");` It's just assigning it as a shorthand for your namespace. Otherwise you'd have to put `urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007` in front of every node in your XPath query in SelectNodes()

Comment: You should perhaps explicitly say that "s" is an example for a _namespace prefix_.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved me a lot of time. Appreciate that!